# Can I safely include an actions.xml file for a specific flavor and omit it for other flavors?

Tags: android, app-actions

Based on my testing using the Test Tool, I believe flavors are supported (I can have 2 different actions.xml files for different flavors of my application).

Despite this, it seems that I need to specify the app actions meta data tag in the Manifest common to all flavors:

```
<!-- Google Assistant App Actions -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.actions"
    android:resource="@xml/actions" />
```

I just want to know if I'd be able to get by with omitting an actions.xml file for the app flavors for which I don't want to support actions, or if I needed to include an empty actions.xml for the other flavor.

In my case, this flavor is published as an entirely different app on the Play Store with a different package name and I don't want to support actions for that app.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know if I'd be able to get by with omitting an actions.xml file for the app flavors for which I don't want to support actions,

If you remove that file your project won't even compile due to broken reference to `@xml/actions`, so you also need to have flavored Manifest file, without that meta-data reference for builds containing no `actions.xml`.

Comment: You're right, that I won't be able to build the flavor without an actions.xml.

The problem is that the test tool doesn't pick up my actions.xml when I include the meta-data block in my flavored Manifest file. It only picked it up when I put it in the common Manifest file.

Comment: Can you try merging [AndroidManifest.xml rule markers](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#merge_rule_markers)?